# When designing digital circuits, which is more power efficient, an if-statement or a multiplication (particular case)?

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I'm currently writing the code of a hardware accelerator in Verilog 2001, and a question has arisen to which I could not find an answer (maybe I don't know how to search for it):

1. There's a simple sequential logic:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
   reg_q <= reg_d;
end
```

2. There's a FSM doing some stuff:

```
always @* begin
   ...
   reg_d = reg_q;
   case(...) begin
      ...
   end
   ...
end
```

And here is the question:

3. I have a simple 1-bit register `A` that under certain circumstances alternates between 1 and 0.
4. The next state of the register `reg_q` depends on some variable `foo` and its dependency coincides with the bit change of `A`. So, there are two things I could do but I don't know whether they are the same or they can produce some differences, let's say in the power consumption of the accelerator, or the area of the circuit. Will it generate the same circuit upon synthesis? Below the two options:

Multiplication:

```
reg_d = reg_q + (foo)*(A)
```

If-statement:

```
reg_d = reg_q
if(A) begin
   reg_d = reg_q + (foo)
end
```

It's my first time asking here and I'm sorry if it's a repeated or non-relevant question.

Comment: If you extend A to the same number of bits as the other registers, then you can do something like `reg_d = reg_q + (foo & ext(A))`.  Boolean logic is certainly going to be simpler than multiplication, though they might be optimized the same anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But extending A would require an additional register to hold the extended sequence of bits, lets say something like `A_ext[127:0] <= {{127{A}}, A}`. Do you think that, by doing so, the power consumption will be negatively affected?

Comment: I don't see why you need a register; just connect A to one input of each of 128 AND gates.  But it's possible I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, yes, I was a bit confused, it can be just a wire `{128{A}}`. It simplifies indeed the logic, but then the question is a bit similar, now between the 3 different approaches of doing it (the two I mentioned and the one you pointed out). Will they be the same upon synthesis and circuit generation?, perhaps some of them are to consume more power. Maybe I'm just complicating it so much, and the power savings, if any, are negligible.

Comment: Its often easier to run the tools than to guess what they are going to do.  In cases like this its not possible to see the logic surrounding which may optimize this logic easily or not depending on the coding style and other factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all combinational logic, it generates the same boolean equations resulting in the same hardware. As long as you don't write code that creates additional latches, there will be no differences in power/area.